# Reverb algorithm causing noise and clipping

Tags: java, algorithm

im new to java programming i general and to DSP-programming i particular, but im trying to apply reverberation to a .wav file. Some of the code i use is from: [Reverb Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318989/reverb-algorithm) but it seems like i dont fully understand it. When i run my code i get a noise that grows over time and eventually also "clipping". I think it has something to do with my buffersize or the fact that im using "clip" to play the reveberated audiostream but im not sure.
I would be very grateful if someone could take a look at it and give some ideas to improve my code.

I use this code:

```
public void Reverbstart() throws InterruptedException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException {

    int bufferLength = 4000_000;
    Clip clip;
    Line line;
    Line.Info linfo = new Line.Info(Clip.class);
    line = AudioSystem.getLine(linfo);
    clip = (Clip) line;

    File sourceFile = new File("some audiofile");

    AudioFileFormat fileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(sourceFile);

    AudioFormat audioFormat = fileFormat.getFormat();

    System.out.println(audioFormat);

    AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sourceFile);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int nBufferSize = bufferLength * audioFormat.getFrameSize();
    byte[]  byteBuffer = new byte[nBufferSize];

    int nBytesRead = ais.read(byteBuffer);
    baos.write(byteBuffer, 0, nBytesRead);

    byte[] AudioData = baos.toByteArray();

    int delayMilliseconds = 3000; 
    int delaySamples = (int)((float)delayMilliseconds * 44.1f); //44100 Hz sample rate
    float decay = 0.5f;

    for (int i = 0; i < AudioData.length - delaySamples; i++){

        AudioData[i] += (short)((float)AudioData[i]);
        AudioData[i + delaySamples] += (short)((float)AudioData[i] * decay);
    }

    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(AudioData);
    AudioInputStream outputAis = new AudioInputStream(bais, audioFormat,AudioData.length/ audioFormat.getFrameSize());


    clip.open(outputAis);

    clip.start();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    System.out.println(clip.getFramePosition());


}
```

Comment: the byte[] is raw data, you are multiplying every array element with the decay factor, depending on format the actual sample is spread over multiple elements, you need to decay each sample not each byte.

Comment: Ok, so im using PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian. But im still not sure what that gives me. I guess i have to multiply the bytes (to get the samples) somewhere?

Comment: That is beyond the scope of what I know. I would try and find out how the bytestream of PCM_SIGNED is defined, probably you can split the data in two channels, apply the decay per channel then merge again to get your audio. I just pointed out what seemed obvious to me, hopefully that is enough to figure out the rest by yourself or we can wait for someone more knowledgeable to come along :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your input anyway :). Im trying to figure it out on my own but i seem to reach dead ends right now. Will read up on reverbalgos.

Comment: Solved it by using bytebuffer to wrap the bytearray and use as a shortbuffer and then back to bytes again. Like this:

Comment: ByteBuffer.wrap(inAudioData).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(shortAudio);

  int delayMilliseconds = 5000; 
  int delaySamples = (int)((float)delayMilliseconds * 44.100); //44100 Hz sample rate
  float decay = 0.3f;

  for (int i = 0; i < shortAudio.length - delaySamples; i++){

    shortAudio[i] += (float)shortAudio[i];
    shortAudio[i + delaySamples] += (float)shortAudio[i]*decay; 
  }

  byte[] outAudio = new byte[shortAudio.length*2];
  ByteBuffer.wrap(outAudio).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().put(shortAudio);

Comment: Could you post the fully working code please for others to see please in a nicely formatted matter?

Comment: @SnytaxErrold Would you please send the final code?

Comment: I faced the same issue and used ByteBuffer part to get rid of distortion and noise but it didnt worked for me. I converted byte to short and after applying effect on short buffer,  converted short to byte back as @arynaq said. How could you solve it ?